# REST API Request using text/xml returns UNSUPPORTED_MEDIA_TYPE

Tags: api, xml, rest

The [documentation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_rest_methods.htm) tells us that XML, however un-hip, can be used as a request format.

The reality seems to be only HTTP 415 errors with `UNSUPPORTED_MEDIA_TYPE`.

Class:

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/zrest/*')
global class ZREST {

    @HttpPost
    global static string doPost(string obj) {
      return 'OK: '+obj;
    }
}
```

Request:

```
POST https://cs8.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/zrest.xml HTTP/1.0
content-length: 37
accept: text/xml
content-type: text/xml
authorization: OAuth ***
user-agent: Whateva
host: cs8.salesforce.com
accept-encoding: gzip

<request>
  <obj>A</obj>
</request>
```

Response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Errors>
    <Error>
        <errorCode>UNSUPPORTED_MEDIA_TYPE</errorCode>
        <message>Content-Type header specified in HTTP request is not supported: text/xml; charset=UTF-8</message>
    </Error>
</Errors>
```

Needless to say it works fine with `application/json` and `{"obj" : "A"}`!

Comment: Did you solve this? I think the 'OK: ' is the problem. Did you try with
 @HttpPost
    global static string doPost(string obj) {
      return obj;
    }

Answer (score 2):

try: `Accept: application/xml` in your request header.